# Django model form render for CreateView takes too long (eventually times out)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using Django generic class views(CreateView) and Django ModelForms. But the form render seems to get stuck for some reason.

Here's my views.py

```
class NewExternalWorkOrder(CreateView):
    model = ExternalWorkOrder
    template_name = 'new_external_work_order.html'
    form_class = ExternalWorkOrderForm
```

My ExternalWorkOrder model:

```
class ExternalWorkOrder(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    inventory_item_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    nature_of_problem = models.TextField()
    mileage_hours = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    #...more fields...
```

and my form class

```
class ExternalWorkOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, * args, ** kwargs):
        super(ExternalWorkOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ExternalWorkOrder
        fields = ['asset', 'inventory_item', 'inventory_item_quantity',
              'nature_of_problem', 'mileage_hours']
        widgets = {
            'asset': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'browser-default'}),
        }
```

All this was working a few days back but it suddenly stopped working. The page now loads forever and the gunicorn worker nearly always times out(I increased the timeout to over 10 minutes). Sometimes it eventually renders.

I had initially thought that it's the form instantiation but after a few more tests, The instantiation seems to complete but the form wouldn't render.

I have updated my views.py to override the get method as

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        context = {'form': form}
        print("About to render with form...")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

If I get rid of the form in context, the page renders successfully.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you check the number of foreign model instances choices in your foreign key fields (*asset* and *inventory_item*).

If they are too much of them, the page can take a really long time to render.

If this is the case, the solution is to implement a lazy loading of model instances in the *select* fields of your HTML. (for example, using [Select2 AJAX capabilities](https://select2.org/)).

Comment: This solved the problem I was having. I had thousands of items on assets. I'd tried to limit the queryset in the ModelForm but while that had made the page render, I got an error that filter can not be used on a sliced queryset when submitting(saving). 

Using django-select2's ModelSelect2Widget solved the problem, if though saving the forms takes too long. Thanks.